# Unable to upload file to server "move_uploaded_file()" error

Tags: php, mysql, file, upload

I can upload files to the server with my computer, but not with others. I've changed the directory permission to 777 already but it still wont work.

```
<?php 
$required = array('name', 'desc');
$error = false;

foreach($required as $field) {
  if (empty($_POST[$field])) {
    $error = true;
  }
}

if ($error) {
  header('Location: error1.php');
} else {
  if (empty($_FILES['photo']['name'])) {
    header('Location: error2.php');
} else {

$target = "bilder/"; 
$target = $target . basename( $_FILES['photo']['name']); 

$name=$_POST['name'];  
$desc=$_POST['desc']; 
$pic=($_FILES['photo']['name']); 

mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "si") or die(mysql_error()) ; 
mysql_select_db("david") or die(mysql_error()) ; 

mysql_query("INSERT INTO `bild` VALUES ('$name', '$desc', '$pic', NOW())") ; 

if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['photo']['tmp_name'], $target)) { 
   header('Location: success.php');
} 
else { 
   header('Location: error3.php');
} 
}
}
?>
```

When I upload the file I get the error message from:

```
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['photo']['tmp_name'], $target)) { 
   header('Location: success.php');
} 
else { 
   header('Location: error3.php');
}
```

Anyone know what the problem might be? thankful for any help!

The html form:

```
<div id="form">
        <form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="add.php" method="POST"> 
            <br>
            <br>
            Titel:<br> <input type="text" name="name" style="width: 300px; height: 50px; font-size: 20px;"><br><br><br>
            Beskrivning: <br><textarea cols="100" rows="8" name="desc" style="font-size: 15px;"></textarea><br><br><br>
            Bild:<br> <input type="file" name="photo" style="height: 40px;"><br><br><br>
            <input type="submit" value="Lägg till" style="height: 40px;"> 
        </form>
</div>
```

Comment: which error message you are getting  check without redirection  about the error and  what the code doing

Comment: why you have tagged sql-server ?

Comment: Share your error message as it is shown to you.

Comment: else { 
   header('Location: error3.php');
} 

will just echo "something went wrong with the upload"

Is there anyway i can change the echo so the error message gets more specific?

Comment: Have you looked in the error log for the web server? If move_uploaded_file fails it will issue a WARNING.

Comment: how do i access the error log?